# Increasing mysql connections

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

We got a big problem with our mysql server setup. We use Zend Framework 2 with Doctrine 2 and PDO Mysql connection.
Our problem is, that the connections shown with mysql > show status are increasing and increasing. It seems like this behavior is slowing our whole application. At the moment the connection count is about 150000. 5 hours before it was about 2000.

We activated persistant connections in php.ini and on the pdo connection. => No change

Can this behavior slow down our whole system or is this normal?

What could be the problem?

Thanks for help

Comment: "...If you don't do this explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends." 

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Are you looking at the `Connections` or `Threads_connected` variable in mysql? `Connections` is the number of connections made since mysql started, whereas `Threads_connected` is the number of active client connections.

Comment: Are you opening a different connection in each function rather than keeping a global connection per PHP page?

Comment: Connections.No i use a global connection. Ok Threads Connected is at 5. Then the problem is anywhere else. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

The 'connections' figure shown on `SHOW STATUS` is the total number of connection attempts made since the server was started (see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections). It's perfectly normal for this number to keep increasing, and it's highly unlikely this is slowing down your application.

If your application is running slowly you should benchmark it to try see where the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 0):

If your server gets bogged down with only 5 active mysql connections I'd suggest you add some timing code to your app to try and pinpoint where the slowdown is. Common reasons could be un-optimized queries, un-optimized mysql, or running queries in loops unnecessarily to name a few.